# Getting progress from a CMD window in Form

Tags: python, vb.net, cmd, console

Im trying to get the progress information from a process that my program executes in CMD (its a python script). I can successfully read each line from the console and send it to a textbox using GetStandardOutput and ReadLine, so that's not a problem.

However when the process initiates a progress bar, no information about it is sent to my textbox and it just waits for the progress to complete before sending any new information. I don't expect the textbox to display a progress bar, but some sort of information like the percentage? So I can parse that data into a progress bar.

The console window looks like this:
[image]

And this is my code for getting the console output:

```
 Private Sub StartConsoleProcess()
     Dim startInfo As New ProcessStartInfo()
     startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe"
     startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
     startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
     startInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
     startInfo.UseShellExecute = False
     startInfo.CreateNoWindow = False
     startInfo.WorkingDirectory = appPath
     startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
     startInfo.Arguments = $"/K title AnimateDiff"

     adProc = New Process()
     adProc.StartInfo = startInfo

     AddHandler adProc.OutputDataReceived, AddressOf ProcessOutputHandler
     AddHandler adProc.ErrorDataReceived, AddressOf ProcessErrorHandler

     adProc.Start()

     adProc.BeginOutputReadLine()
     adProc.BeginErrorReadLine()
 End Sub

 Private Sub ProcessOutputHandler(sender As Object, e As DataReceivedEventArgs)
     If e.Data IsNot Nothing Then
         AppendOutputText(e.Data)
     End If
 End Sub

 Private Sub ProcessErrorHandler(sender As Object, e As DataReceivedEventArgs)
     If e.Data IsNot Nothing Then
         AppendOutputText(e.Data)
     End If
 End Sub

 Private Sub AppendOutputText(text As String)
     If ConsoleOutput.InvokeRequired Then
         ConsoleOutput.Invoke(New Action(Of String)(AddressOf AppendOutputText), text)
     Else
         ConsoleOutput.AppendText(text & Environment.NewLine)
     End If
 End Sub
```

Comment: @modi I should clarify that I didn't create the python program. Only the VB UI to interact with it. My program simply writes a file and sends it to the python script to process. Im just trying to capture that process info. Im not worried about users not having one of the programs installed because they wouldnt and shouldnt be using my app if they didnt.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else has this same issue I managed to solve it in a very simple way.

The issue was that the Python script was using tqdm.rich. By removing ".rich" and using regular tqdm you can capture the progress bar via standard output.

So in the python script I changed:

```
from tqdm.rich import tqdm
```

to:

```
from tqdm import tqdm
```

Hope that helps!